# Provide email certificate in html mailto link

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, x509, mailto

I would like to know if it's possible to provide an email certificate (signed by a recognised CA) so the user clicking on the mailto link can send encrypted email to the owner of the cert ?

```
<a href="mailto:hello@gmail.com">hello@gmail.com</a>
```

Is there any way to do that using the mailto link or using some JS ? Given the mailto link is handled by a local email client, should be possible ?

If there is no direct way to do this, how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up what you according to the current specification can do with a mailto URL in [RFC 2368](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2368.html). You'll see that it only refers to the construction of the mail text and headers, not their encoding or encryption. There may be extensions for some mail clients, but that's not something one should generally count on.

Furthermore, Web mail users generally will have problems with such links anyways. Thus, for a solution that has to be usable by anyone, a scheme counting on some client side program is not a good choice.

Thus, some Web form as mentioned by @Eugene accessable only via https would best serve your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

One option is a web form for message sending, served via HTTPS. The server-side handler of the form would compose an encrypted mail on the server and then send it via SMTP. This provides almost the same level of security as direct encryption (given that your server is secure). Unfortunately there's no other simple way to do what you want. Of course, you can put a link for your .cer file download and tell the user to download the .cer file and use it to compose an encrypted mail, but how would you deal with GMail users and mobile users? Web form is more flexible and easier to use for the sender.